# Import Error: Missing optional dependecy 'openpyxl.'

Tags: python, terminal, pip, openpyxl, importerror

I am familiar with using pip to install Python packages but there is no way to install it in the environment I am working in. We have to call the directory with `python.exe` to run any Python code. Therefore, it is impossible to use `pip install` because, since there is no python, there is no pip. How could we install packages without using pip or installing pip via the python.exe file? Here is an image of the error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages like pip can be executed from the python executable using `python.exe -m pip install openpyxl`. If you don't have sufficient firewall permissions (as you mentioned high security) you may not be able to connect to the package servers, which you would need to discuss with admin.